# How to redirect to page depending path using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

How can I rewrite on htaccess for redirect

`mysite.com/test/`

to

`mysite.com/main.php`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work

```
RewriteRule "^/test/" "main.php"
```

(not tested)